# How much gold is there in our sun?

Tags: the-sun

[XKCD 1944](https://xkcd.com/1944/) claims that there is "more gold in the sun than water in the oceans". Is this really true?

[image: The end of the rainbow]

Comment: Who here would dare contradict xkcd.com ? :-)

Comment: Alt text for people that don't want to click through to XKCD: _"The retina is the exposed surface of the brain, so if you think about a pot of gold while looking at a rainbow, then there's one at BOTH ends."_

Comment: It was already explained on http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1944

Comment: @StephenG Much as I hate to contradict XKCD, that's not how rainbows work. You don't get a partial rainbow if there's simply a cloud in the right position. It has to be raindrops.

Comment: Also discussed in the [xkcd forum](http://fora.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=124122#p4298000).

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The mass of the sun is 1.989 × 10<sup>30</sup> kg.

[Abundance in the Sun of the elements](http://www.periodictable.com/Properties/A/SolarAbundance.html) gives a percentage 1 × 10<sup>-7</sup> % [for gold](http://www.periodictable.com/Elements/079/data.html) <sup>*</sup>, so that leaves you with a mass of 1.989 × 10<sup>21</sup> kg of gold.

[HowStuffWorks states](https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/earth/geophysics/question157.htm) that there is 1.26 × 10<sup>21</sup> kg water on Earth, of which 98% is in the oceans, i.e. 1.235 × 10<sup>21</sup> kg.

This would mean the XKCD statement is true: there is 1.6 times as much gold in the sun as there is water in the oceans.

<sup>* They cite WolframAlpha as their source. Executing [SolarAbundance "Gold"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SolarAbundance+%22Gold%22) there confirms this (mass) percentage.</sup>

Comment: There are at least two problems with that calculation: (1) The source for abundance doesn't say whether the percentage is of mass or of number of atoms; (2) if is it percentage of mass, 1 × 10<sup>-7</sup> % means somewhere between 0.5 × 10<sup>-7</sup> % and 1.5 × 10<sup>-7</sup> %, so the proportion could be as low as 0.8, which is less than 1.

Comment: How did that gold get there?  I am under the impression that, as a main sequence star, the sun cannot create its own gold through element synthesis.  So I am guessing that the gold in the sun was present when the sun first started burning, and I guess it must come from older generation supernovae?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese Correct, virtually all of the elements heavier than Helium in the Sun (and the rest of the solar system) are the remains of older stars.

Comment: @ Peter Taylor, similarly, the XKCD cartoon doesn't state whether it is more by mass or more by number of atoms/molecules.

Comment: @Octopus or by volume.  2 lbs of gold is quite a bit smaller than 1 lb of sea-water.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese yes -- the same way it got in the earth :)

Comment: What is the uncertainty of this abundance-of-gold-in-the-Sun estimate?  Without uncertainty estimates, the question which one is more cannot be answered.

Comment: "1 × 10-7 %" sound really weird. Would 1 part per billion be better, or do we run into American versus British English problems?

Comment: @gerrit That is always the case. Mathematically speaking, since the abundance is given with only one significant digit, the answer should be too. But we are talking about a comic here, not a scientific publication.

Answer (score 31):

["Element Abundances in the Sun - The Elements Handbook", *KnowledgeDoor*](http://www.knowledgedoor.com/2/elements_handbook/element_abundances_in_the_sun.html) claims that the base 10 log of the number of atoms of gold in the Sun for every $10^{12}$ atoms of hydrogen is $1.01 \pm 0.15$. If I'm reading their references correctly, that's from **Abundances of the Elements: Meteoritic and Solar**, Anders, Edward, and Nicolas Grevesse, *Geochimica et Cosmochimica Acta*, volume 53, number 1, 1989, pp. 197–214, doi:10.1016/0016-7037(89)90286-X

The atomic mass of gold is $197$ times the atomic mass of hydrogen (more precise figures are available, but irrelevant given the accuracy of the atomic proportions). So $2020$ kg of gold for every $10^{12}$ kg of hydrogen, meaning that ignoring all other elements and running with $1.99 \times 10^{30}$ kg for the mass of the Sun, it contains $4 \times 10^{21}$ kg of gold. Taking other elements into account - helium is actually significant - reduces that value to $3 \times 10^{21}$ kg.

This is about twice as much as the mass of the ocean, which corresponds to 2 standard deviations ($\log_{10} 2 \approx 0.3$ vs the standard deviation of $0.15$ in the log 10 value of the abundance).

Comment: The 10^1.01 number is the abundance *in the photosphere* relative to H=10^12 .  Elements other than H are expected to be gravitationally depleted in the photosphere, so this number is not representative of the entire sun. See section 2.2.1.2.2 here: https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10036398

Comment: @DavePhD, so in other words this is an under-estimate, strengthening the conclusion?

Comment: yes, an underestimate